# Why is a System.ArgumentException occurring on the second or third iteration of a cryptographic line of code?

Tags: vb.net, argumentexception

I'm getting the following error after executing code that deals with cryptography:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt32'.

A few sources (e.g. http://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/fix-sitecore-and-net-framework-4-5/ ) where a similar error occurred say to change a value to the following in Web.config (pardon the space after the "less than" sign):

`< setting name=”Login.RememberLastLoggedInUserName” value=”false” />`

I have never used a Web.config file before, so this could be the solution. However, my project doesn't have one (I'm not sure if it could have one since I don't think it has a web site name) and I don't know why there were apparent successes in the previous iteration(s). Anyway, here is the portion of my code that contains the problem (I took out some irrelevant code):

`Dim stream As IO.FileStream
    Dim dataOffset As Int64
    Dim dataSize As Int64
    Dim del2 As New ChangeProgress2Delegate(AddressOf ChangeProgress2)`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim fileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    fileDialog.ShowDialog()
    stream = New IO.FileStream(fileDialog.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim t As New Threading.Tasks.Task(AddressOf Perform)
    t.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Perform()
    Dim Key(15) As [Byte]
    Dim Bytes(15) As [Byte]
    Dim IV(15) As [Byte]
    Dim userData(31743) As [Byte]
    Dim encryption2 As Security.Cryptography.Aes
    Dim decryptor2 As Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform
    Dim msDecrypt2 As IO.MemoryStream
    Dim csDecrypt2 As Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream
    For i As UInt32 = 0 To 3
        .
        .
        .
        For j As UInt32 = 0 To (numPartitions - 1)
            .
            .
            .
            dataOffset = Convert.ToUInt32((Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 24) + (Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 16) + (Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 8) + Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte())) >> 2
            dataSize = Convert.ToUInt32((Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 24) + (Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 16) + (Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte()) << 8) + Convert.ToUInt64(stream.ReadByte())) >> 2
            stream.Position = dataOffset
            For k = 0 To ((dataSize / 32768) - 1)
                stream.Position += 976
                stream.Read(IV, 0, 16)
                stream.Position += 32
                stream.Read(userData, 0, 31744)
                encryption2 = Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create()
                encryption2.Key = Key
                encryption2.IV = IV
                encryption2.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
                decryptor2 = encryption2.CreateDecryptor(encryption2.Key, encryption2.IV)
                msDecrypt2 = New IO.MemoryStream(userData)
                csDecrypt2 = New Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msDecrypt2, decryptor2, Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                csDecrypt2.Read(userData, 0, 31744)
                stream.Position -= 31744
                stream.Write(userData, 0, 31744)
                Debugger.Break()
                Me.BeginInvoke(del2, {i + 1, j + 1, numPartitions})
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ChangeProgress2(ByVal partitionOrder As UInt32, ByVal partitionNum As UInt32, ByVal numPartitions As UInt32)
    Progress.Value = ((stream.Position - dataOffset) / dataSize) * 100
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub ChangeProgress2Delegate(ByVal partitionOrder As UInt32, ByVal partitionNum As UInt32, ByVal numPartitions As UInt32)
```

In the code above, the error has been firing somewhat randomly between these three lines of code on the second or third iteration:

`decryptor2 = encryption2.CreateDecryptor(encryption2.Key, encryption2.IV)
                    msDecrypt2 = New IO.MemoryStream(userData)
                    csDecrypt2 = New Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msDecrypt2, decryptor2, Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Read)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It didn't have to do with any cryptography even though the exception was firing around those lines of code. At the `BeginInvoke` line, I needed to convert the parameters into `UInt32` so that code looked like:

`Me.BeginInvoke(del2, {Convert.ToUInt32(i + 1), Convert.ToUInt32(j + 1), Convert.ToUInt32(numPartitions)})`

I had to do this even though `i` was a `UInt32`, `j` was a `UInt32`, and `numPartitions` was a `UInt32`.